# Cambiar el color de la letra de un control cuando está desabilitado en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un `EditText` que si lo desabilito con `setEnable(false)`, me gustaría cambiar el color de la letra, fondo etc...

Comment: A mi también me gustaría saber eso, alguna vez un requerimiento fue cambiar el color cuando no estuviera habilitado pero nunca se realizo. El problema es un listener adecuado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar el color del control de la letra y fondo, se puede realizar usando un selector de estado.

**Color de la letra**

Definir el color de la letra en modo normal y el color cuando este desabilitado el control.

*res/color/selector_color_1.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- disabled state -->
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#ff8400" />
  <item android:color="#000"/>
</selector>
```

En `style.xml` definir un estilo con el nombre `editTextStyle` o cualquiera.

```
<style name="editTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_color_1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

En el layout xml donde se diseña el control, con el atributo `style` se le asigna el estilo `editTextStyle`

```
<EditText
    ...
    style="@style/editTextStyle" />
```

Cuando se realiza EditText.setEnabled(false) se le asignará el el color establecido en el selector, estado `state_enabled="false"`

**Color del fondo / background**

Para el fondo usaremos otro selector, pero obtendremos lo siguiente, si usamos el mismo selector del color del texto:

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   3:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Para asignar el color de fondo lo haremos en `android:drawable`

*res/color/selector_color_2.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/colorBackEnabledTrue" android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
  <item android:drawable="@color/colorBackEnabledFalse" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</selector>
```

Los colores tampoco los podemos asignar directamente con el formato `#000000` lo deberemos asignarlos a `res/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="colorBackEnabledFalse">#dcdcdc</color>
    <color name="colorBackEnabledTrue">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

y en `style.xml` añadir

```
<style name="editTextStyle">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">@color/selector_color_2</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Excelente!!! muchas gracias por la aportación! Pero se puede cambiar el color de la letra y el fondo??? =0

Comment: Ahora lo pruebo, que solo lo he hecho con la letra

Comment: Si veo que los dos no se puede, reedito la pregunta y respuesta

Comment: No ser si la solución está en este hilo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383204/statelist-drawable-androidstate-enabled-not-working-in-xml voy intentando

Comment: Solucionado, tanto para el color de la letra como el fondo.